# co-authoring in Microsoft Project

Tags: ms-project, project-online, ms-project-server-2016

We would like to manage a project structure where individual projects can take a part in a top level project structure sharing a single resource pool. It should be possible for individual authors to work on those individual projects, or possibly the same project, at the same time.

We are familiar with co-authoring in excel, word, etc (through sharepoint) and it works fine. We have licences for MS project 2019. But we can't seem to find a way to set up co-authoring, or find any definite statement as to whether it is even possible with project.

I have seen "Microsoft Project Server 2019" and "Project Online" mentioned, are these different products and are these needed?

Any guidance or info about this would be much appreciated,

Answer (score 4):

Project Online is the Azure based version of the good old Project Server for on-premises. Both are so called Enterprise Project and Portfolio Management Tools. If you are looking for co-authoring in sense of concurrent editing, you will not be satisfied with both of them: You must checkout and checkin a plan for editing. If you are looking for true concurrent co-authoring you should take a look at the oncoming new Project Service. It explicitly allows co-authoring. Nevertheless it starts with very limited features, it is supposed to grow soon and fast.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blog/2018/09/25/a-new-vision-for-modern-work-management-with-microsoft-project/

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Project-Blog/A-letter-to-our-Microsoft-Project-community/ba-p/260891

Comment: Many thanks. Maybe our expectations are too high. As a second best, is there any way to set up 2 independent projects which can be edited simultaneously by 2 authors, which share a single resource pool?

Comment: Yes! It's one of the key features of Project Server and Project Online to have a shared enterprise resource pool and a scheduling engine that allocates and levels  ressources according to existing assigments in other Projects.

Comment: ok we found this: https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/create-and-share-a-resource-pool-64a2416e-b811-4ddf-b039-e0347e233581  - but could not find a way to make it work with independent projects. So author A editing project A has to lock the resource pool and project B while he edits project A so author B cannot work on project B at the same time

Comment: You Need to store your project on Project Online in order to have the Enterprise Resource Pool available and then your can achieve your goal.

Comment: Kurt's answer is correct, but getting your head around Project Online can be tricky at first. If you want some help I could probably walk you through it in on a web call in about 15 mins; reach out on LinkedIn if you need to.